# Android: Check if a process was completed to start other

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm having problems with layout inflated by ViewPagerIndicator and processes within runnable.
It's not always that happens, but already happened few times.

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mAdapter = new GtAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        mIndicator.setCurrentItem(1);
        mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {   
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
        int cod = mAdapter.getItemPosition(0);

        refreshPages();

    }
```

On refreshPages() method, I have a Runnable, that make some references to views inflated by ViewPagerIndicator, this usually works, but sometimes (~ 20 works - 1 error) I get some NullPointerException errors in that references.

I put some logging tags by the code, and found that when the error occurs, the refreshPages  method occurred before the inflate process was initiated. why does this happen?
How can I make the refreshPages method be started only after the inflate process was completed? Thanks

Comment: If you have problems with `refreshPages`, why not show that code?

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel,

Since refreshPages has or implements a Runnable, the code for it runs on a **different thread.** You don't have control when a thread gets executed; it just does. This is the reason of why sometimes your code does not work. One quick way is to synchronize threads using a shared flag (between threads) or the more right way using a semaphore. For now, just experiment using a flag until you understand how to synchronize. Understand?

As suggested before, you may supply the code for refreshPages(), for review.